# Understanding `mod_rewrite`: internally redirect `foo.txt` to `foo.txt.cgi` where `foo.txt` doesn't exist?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cgi

My goal is to serve `.txt` files out of a directory, but where a particular `.txt` file does not exist, I want to perform an ***internal*** redirect to a similarly named `.txt.cgi` script, if such a script exists. This question pertains to why one approach seems to work, but two alternate approaches do ***not*** work.

I have the following directory structure (i.e., as a subdirectory somewhere in `/var/www` or the equivalent):

```
% ls -ARl rewritecgi
total 0
drwxr-sr-x  2 posita  posita  170 Mar 16 14:36 test1
drwxr-sr-x  2 posita  posita  170 Mar 16 14:38 test2
drwxr-sr-x  2 posita  posita  170 Mar 16 14:38 test3

rewritecgi/test1:
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 posita  posita  288 Mar 16 14:36 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 posita  posita   28 Mar 16 14:34 other.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 posita  posita  143 Mar 16 14:20 test.txt.cgi

rewritecgi/test2:
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 posita  posita  301 Mar 16 14:38 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 posita  posita   28 Mar 16 14:34 other.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 posita  posita  143 Mar 16 14:19 test.txt.cgi

rewritecgi/test3:
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 posita  posita  288 Mar 16 14:38 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 posita  posita   28 Mar 16 14:34 other.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 posita  posita  143 Mar 16 14:20 test.txt.cgi
```

`other.txt` in each `test{1,2,3}` subdirectory is just a plain old text file.

`test.txt.cgi` in each `test{1,2,3}` subdirectory contains:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
cat <<EOF
Content-Type: text/plain

Hi! I'm \`${0}\`!
EOF
```

`test1/.htaccess` is as follows:

```sh
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~posita/rewritecgi/test1/
<Files ~ "\.cgi$">
    Options +ExecCGI
</Files>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^(.*\.txt)$" "$1.cgi"
```

`test2/.htaccess` is the same as `test1/.htaccess`, but moves `+ExecCGI` to the top level (I get a `403` if I use `<Files>`) and adds the `[H=cgi-script]` flag to `RewriteRule`:

```sh
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~posita/rewritecgi/test2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^(.*\.txt)$" "$1.cgi" [H=cgi-script]
```

The [`mod_rewrite` documentation for the `H` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_h) suggests this should work.

`test3/.htaccess` is the same as `test1/.htaccess`, but enables the `+MultiViews` option:

```sh
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes +MultiViews
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~posita/rewritecgi/test3/
<Files ~ "\.cgi$">
    Options +ExecCGI
</Files>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^(.*\.txt)$" "$1.cgi"
```

Unsurprisingly, all of the `other.txt` files resolve without issue:

```
% for i in 1 2 3 ; do echo "----> ${i} <----" ; curl --location --post30{1,2,3} --silent "http://localhost/~posita/rewritecgi/test${i}/other.txt" ; done
----> 1 <----
Just a plain old text file.
----> 2 <----
Just a plain old text file.
----> 3 <----
Just a plain old text file.
```

All three `test.txt.cgi` scripts run properly when called explicitly:

```
% for i in 1 2 3 ; do echo "----> ${i} <----" ; curl --location --post30{1,2,3} --silent "http://localhost/~posita/rewritecgi/test${i}/test.txt.cgi" ; done
----> 1 <----
Hi! I'm `/.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test1/test.txt.cgi`!
----> 2 <----
Hi! I'm `/.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt.cgi`!
----> 3 <----
Hi! I'm `/.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test3/test.txt.cgi`!
```

However, only `http://localhost/~posita/rewritecgi/test1/test.txt` redirects to the CGI:

```html
% for i in 1 2 3 ; do echo "----> ${i} <----" ; curl --location --post30{1,2,3} --silent "http://localhost/~posita/rewritecgi/test${i}/test.txt" ; done
----> 1 <----
Hi! I'm `/.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test1/test.txt.cgi`!
----> 2 <----
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /~posita/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
----> 3 <----
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /~posita/rewritecgi/test3/test.txt was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

With `RewriteLogLevel 9` I get the following log messages for `http://localhost/~posita/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt`:

```
==> /var/log/apache2/rewrite_log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (3) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/] strip per-dir prefix: /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt -> test.txt
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (3) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/] applying pattern '^(.*\\.txt)$' to uri 'test.txt'
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (4) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/] RewriteCond: input='/.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt' pattern='!-f' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (4) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/] RewriteCond: input='/.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt' pattern='!-d' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (2) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/] rewrite 'test.txt' -> 'test.txt.cgi'
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (3) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/] add per-dir prefix: test.txt.cgi -> /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt.cgi
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (2) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/] remember /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt.cgi to have Content-handler 'cgi-script'
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (2) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/] trying to replace prefix /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/ with /~posita/rewritecgi/test2/
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt.cgi -> test.txt.cgi
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (4) add subst prefix: test.txt.cgi -> /~posita/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt.cgi
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (1) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test2/] internal redirect with /~posita/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt.cgi [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb3788abea0/initial] (1) force filename redirect:/~posita/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt.cgi to have the Content-handler 'cgi-script'

==> /var/log/apache2/access_log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:30:42 -0700] "GET /~posita/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 229

==> /var/log/apache2/error_log <==
[Mon Mar 16 15:30:42 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script not found or unable to stat: redirect:/~posita/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt.cgi
```

And for `http://localhost/~posita/rewritecgi/test3/test.txt`:

```
==> /var/log/apache2/rewrite_log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:35:47 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb37889aea0/subreq] (3) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test3/] strip per-dir prefix: /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test3/test.txt.cgi -> test.txt.cgi
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:35:47 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb37889aea0/subreq] (3) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test3/] applying pattern '^(.*\\.txt)$' to uri 'test.txt.cgi'
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:35:47 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb37889aea0/subreq] (1) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test3/] pass through /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test3/test.txt.cgi

==> /var/log/apache2/access_log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:35:47 -0700] "GET /~posita/rewritecgi/test3/test.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 229

==> /var/log/apache2/error_log <==
[Mon Mar 16 15:35:47 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test3/test.txt (None could be negotiated).
```

So what gives? Why would adding `[H=cgi-script]` cause `test2` not to call the CGI? For `test3`, why would enabling `+MultiViews` circumvent `mod_rewrite`? I know [`mod_rewrite` is voodoo](http://www.rcbowen.com/speaks/slides/modrewrite/#/step-2), but I really do want to understand the nuances between these situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiviews is the option to look for files in other directories if it is not found in the current one. That implies that it finding results is not restricted to the same directory, not that it circumvents mod_rewrite. It uses mod_negotiation. Using the option Multiviews let the server choose, based on the pattern what is the best file to chose. That is not the situation imo you are after when using .htaccess and mod_rewrite. I never use it.

What I noticed are the RewriteConds in your .htaccess. They are not required. I got it working without them. The more you specify in .htaccess, the more problems you can have. (Rewrite can be voodoo indeed.)
I made a .htaccess file without those conditions and it worked:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /StackoverflowQuestions/tests/cgi/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.txt$ $1.cgi [L]
```

That is enough to make it working. Now is the RewriteRule resolving to the same filename only another extension and not filename + extension.
In the handler tag [H...] do you need to specify the mime-type of the cgi file. That is application/x-httpd-cgi, not cgi-script. But you do not need to specify the H-flag when you use AddHandler.

Comment: If I eliminate the `RewriteCond`s, `http://localhost/~posita/rewritecgi/test1/other.txt` results in a `404`.

Comment: Also, changing `[H=cgi-script]` to `[H=application/x-httpd-cgi]` has no effect. `http://localhost/~posita/rewritecgi/test2/test.txt` still results in a `404`. Note that in my original question, `http://localhost/~posita/rewritecgi/test1/test.txt` ***already*** works. The question is why do the other two ***not*** work? (Although I accept that `MultiViews` is something that potentially conflicts with `mod_rewrite`, and that the two should not be mixed.)

Comment: What's weird to me in the `+MultiViews` test is the `rewrite_log` entry suggesting that it should resolve to the CGI: `127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:35:47 --0700] [localhost/sid#7fb378812308][rid#7fb37889aea0/subreq] (1) [perdir /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test3/] pass through /.../posita/public_html/rewritecgi/test3/test.txt.cgi`.

Comment: If you remove -MultiViews from your first list of options in your first .htaccess, then will you not have any 404 anymore. That is how it worked at least on my server.

Comment: My remark about the [H=...] is not that it should work, but that if you read the documentation, that you should make use of the mime-type. cgi-script Is not the mime-type of a cgi-file. In my previous comment should I have said remove -Multiviews from the options list and then will you not have any internal server error due to the disabled RewriteConds.

Comment: Maybe should I have been more clear about why the second .htaccess file does not work: because of the H-flag. If you remove that flag from the .htaccess file, then works that .htaccess too.

Comment: I didn't mean to seem unappreciative of your effort. It does provide some insight. Let me ask the question in a different way: If I really *wanted* to use the `[H=...]` approach (instead of using `AddHandler`), how could I make that work? `[H=application/x-httpd-cgi]` doesn't seem to do the trick for me?

Comment: Also, @loek-bergman, you wrote, "If you remove -MultiViews from your first list of options in your first .htaccess, then will you not have any 404 anymore." I was never getting `404` responses with my first `.htaccess`. Only my second and third. The first one works. I'm sorry if this wasn't clear in my original post.

Comment: The rewriteconds are not needed. They are created for situations to define conditions under which a rule should be applied. This rule must always be applied, hence the rewriteconds should not be there ideally. When I commented them out, there was an exception thrown. Removing the -Multiviews out of the options list solved that problem. Your first one did work, but I will always try to make code more concise and less error prone. .htaccess is used with every request. If it can be done with less, then will that have a positive on the performance of every request.

Comment: I wrote from memory when I said that the H-flag should not work, but that you should at least use the mime-type. Here is documentation from Apache that says it too: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html#nonscriptalias. You need the combination of ExecCGI and AddHandler to make it work.

Comment: Ah, I see, so `[H=...]` really just means "treat this thing that has a default handler of X like this other thing that has a handler of Y", but all the requirements for setting up executable things that handle X or Y are still present? That makes sense now.

Comment: Regarding `RewriteCond`s and `-MultiViews`, what you say may be true for the environment your `.htaccess` inherits from your Apache installation, but it's certainly ***not*** true for mine. If I emulate what you describe, accessing ***either*** `other.txt` or `test.txt` results in `404`s. I'm curious to know what you have in your setup where the net effect of your proposal is the same as my explicit configuration....

Comment: I'm marking this as answered, although this still feels like voodoo magic to me. I will strive for acceptance.